# Correct way to pass local variables from a controller to a js.erb which renders a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to implement an edit function for comments using ajax. The function must load a _form.html.erb partial to edit the comment on which the user clicks but I am not able to figure out how to implement the variables used.

```
def edit
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
  @post = Post.find_by_id(params[:post_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {}
    format.json { head :no_content }
    format.js { render "edit", :locals => {:@comment => Comment.find(params[:id]), :@post => @post} }
  end
end

def update
@comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
@post = Post.find_by_id(params[:post_id])
if @comment.update_attributes(comment_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated comment"
    redirect_to post_path(@comment)
    }
    format.json { head :no_content }
    format.js
  end
else
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html {flash[:alert] = "Error updating coment"
    render :edit
    flash[:alert] = "Error updating coment"
    render :edit}
    format.json { head :no_content }
    format.js
  end 
end
end
```

Here are my js files, edit and update:

```
$('.edit_comment').bind('ajax:success', function() {
$(this).closest('.comment').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'comments/form', :locals => {:post => @post,:comment => @comment}) %>");});



$('.edit_comment').bind('ajax:success', function() {
$(this).closest('.comment').replaceWith('<%=j render 'comments/comment', post: @post, comment: @comment%>');
});
```

There must be some problem with the variables I'm using in my controller and in my js files because when I try and edit more than one comment without refreshing I am always editing the first one I clicked on.

In my console the right comment ids are given when I click on edit, however when the form is loaded on the actual page it is using always the first comment that I tried to edit.

**EDIT**

adding my form partial:

```
<%= form_for [post, comment], remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :body, placeholder: "Add a Comment" %><br/>
  <%= f.submit "Post Comment"  %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Try changing this `format.js { render "edit", :locals => {:@comment => Comment.find(params[:id]), :@post => @post} }` to `format.js`

Comment: Please share your form partial.

Comment: @Pavan changing  to format.js doesn't fix the problem.